# Wrong "deceptive site ahead" warning on my github pages domain

Tags: github, web, subdomain, github-pages, netlify

## Description

It all started with the development of the 'Netflix Clone App.' Even though I had only used HTML and CSS, I had managed to recreate everything exactly the same way (favicon, title, etc.). In short, I hadn't thought there would be a problem. However, when I received a 'Deceptive Site Ahead' warning on a red screen, I realized I had to remove everything. My domain got blacklisted.

## What I tried to solve?

I made two requests within this week using Google Search Console, and additionally, I used a service provided by Google to report incorrect phishing.

## Whats my domain name?

Github uses [username.github.io]. My github username is emiryncr.

*To deploy mini projects, I decided to use netlify instead of github, I just want to clear warnings*